# How do I get a destroy method to work for nested resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

Currently learning Ruby on Rails and creating a simple blog app with comments. I have a `Comment` model and an `Article` model. `Comment` is polymorphic and both models have many comments.

I'm trying to come up with a `destroy` method that's able to delete both the comments that belong to `Comment` and the ones that belong to `Article` (and that remain as [deleted] without destroying their children, much like in Reddit, although I haven't even gotten to that part).

I have tried different paths but I haven't got it right yet. Nested paths still confuse me a little and I'm not sure on how to pass the params that the path requests when creating the `link_to`.

These are my files:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'comments/new'
  get 'comments/create'
  get 'articles/index'
  get 'articles/show'
  root 'articles#index'

resources :articles  do 
    resources :comments
end
resources :comments do 
    resources :comments
end


end
```

article.rb:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: :true
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_commentable

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end 

  def destroy
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def find_commentable
    if params[:article_id]
      @commentable = Article.find_by_id(params[:article_id])
    elsif params[:comment_id]      
      @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])
    end
  end

end
```

show.html.erb, where the form for commments that belong to `Article.rb` is:

```
<h1> <%= @article.title %> </h1>
<p> <%= @article.body %> </p>
<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@article.created_at) %> ago </small> <br/>

<h3>Comments</h3>

<%= form_for [@article, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Say something!" %> <br/>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<ul class="parent-comment">
    <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "Index", articles_path %>
```

And the partial `_comment.html.erb` , which displays the comments that belong to the article as well as those that belong to other comments, and where I'm trying to integrate the `link_to`:

```
<p> <%= comment.body %> </p>
<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago </small> <br/>

<%= form_for [comment, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a reply!" %><br/>
    <%= f.submit "Reply" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete %>
<% end %>

<ul>
    <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments %>
</ul>
```

Whenever I do seem to get the path right, `` NoMethodError in CommentsController#destroy  — undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass `` comes up. Why would the controller show it as undefined? It worked in the `new` method, as far as I can see.

Could you give some guidance as to what I should do or what I should fix? I'm not sure how to delete the parent comments, either, and I haven't managed to find information that suits this case. If you know where to point me to, I'm all eyes.

Thank you.

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: @hashrocket. Sorry, I've added them now.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your design model structure.

Your view

```
<%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete %>
```

Your find_commentable

```
   elsif params[:comment_id]      
         @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])
   end
```

@commentable will be a Comment class, so it won't have `.comments` methods as your **Article** class

Answer (score 0):

check carefully to destroy the method

```
  def destroy
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end
```

use `@comment = @commentable.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])` and check whether `@comment` has some value or not?

just add one condition like this and it won't throw the error:

```
@comment.destroy if @comment
```

if `@comment` is `nil` and trying to destroy then it will throw the error.